# Candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter: <const T &> vs <T &>

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a member function `_wrapper` in my class, that encapsulates some common logic around family of other functions. This wrapper function accepts pointer to function that is being wrapped and its arguments.

Wrapper in my class is implemented similar to how it is done in this example class `Foo`:

```
#include <functional>

class Foo
{
public:
    void bar1(int a)
    {
        /// No-op.
    }

    void bar1(int a, int b)
    {
        /// No-op.
    }

    void bar2(const int & a)
    {
        /// No-op.
    }

    void foo(int x)
    {
        _wrapper_bar1(x);           /// No problems to deduce type
        _wrapper_bar2(x);           /// No problems to deduce type

        _wrapper(&Foo::bar1, x);    /// Deduction fails
        _wrapper(&Foo::bar2, x);    /// Deduction fails
    }

private:
    template <typename ...Args>
    void _wrapper(void (Foo::*method) (Args ...), Args && ...args)
    {
        /// Do some common stuff here...

        (this->*method)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template <typename ...Args>
    void _wrapper_bar1(Args && ...args)
    {
        bar1(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template <typename ...Args>
    void _wrapper_bar2(Args && ...args)
    {
        bar2(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Foo().foo(123);
    return 0;
}
```

When I pass an `lvalue`, `foo`'s argument `int x`, to the wrapper, `clang` compiler complaints that there is a conflict and deduction fails:

```
test.cpp:21:9: error: no matching member function for call to '_wrapper'
        _wrapper(&Foo::bar1, x);    /// Deduction fails
        ^~~~~~~~
test.cpp:27:10: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'Args' (<int> vs. <int &>)
    void _wrapper(void (Foo::*method) (Args ...), Args && ...args)
         ^
test.cpp:22:9: error: no matching member function for call to '_wrapper'
        _wrapper(&Foo::bar2, x);    /// Deduction fails
        ^~~~~~~~
test.cpp:27:10: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'Args' (<const int &> vs. <int &>)
    void _wrapper(void (Foo::*method) (Args ...), Args && ...args)
```

The thing is I don't understand why is this happening. It is okay to pass just `lvalue` alone, as it is done using `_wrapper_bar1` and `_wrapper_bar2`. And doing so does not rise any conflict of this sort, ie `const T &` vs `T &`.

I know a way around this error: by casting `lvalue` to an `rvalue` using `std::move(x)`, but obviously it is not a fix, since move is not actually needed. Also, sometimes I need to use `x` after calling wrapper function, and using moved value is an UB.

Probably my template is very broken and I am missing some obvious thing. I'd appreciate your help.

**Edit:** overloaded `Foo::bar1()`

Comment: In `template <typename ...Args> void _wrapper(void (Foo::*method) (Args ...), Args && ...args)` note that the second Args force rvalue reference...

Comment: @Jarod42, well, it is actually an *universal reference*, it does not force rvalue.

Comment: I mean that it is in the member function pointer, and in normal param. You may want `template <typename ...Args, typename... Arg2s> void _wrapper(void (Foo::*method) (Args ...), Arg2s && ...args)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In

```
template <typename ...Args>
void _wrapper(void (Foo::*method) (Args ...), Args && ...args)
```

`Args` may be deduced from 2 places.

You may solve that by introducing an other template arguments:

```
template <typename ...Args, typename ...Arg2s>
void _wrapper(void (Foo::*method) (Args ...), Arg2s&& ...args)
{
    /// Do some common stuff here...

    (this->*method)(std::forward<Arg2s>(args)...);
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/Sid9nN)

Comment: you can even do `template <typename Method, typename ...Args>
void _wrapper(Method method, Args&& ...args)
{
    (this->*method)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}`

Comment: This solution does not work if `bar*` is overloaded, unfortunately. Should I update my answer and add an overloaded version?

Comment: If `bar` is overloaded, it would be ambiguous for `(Foo::*method) (Args ...)`. so you have to specify which one you want (`_wrapper(static_cast<void (Foo::*)(int)>&Foo::bar1, x);`) or force `Args...` to be in a non deductible context (and to be of the correct type).